# Powershell's equivalent of "set -x" in bash?

Tags: bash, powershell

In `bash` you can use `set -x` which will print the executed command line. If, for example, you have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

echo "Hello world!"
```

The output will be

```
+ echo "Hello world!"
Hello world
```

The first line contains `+` which indicates the executed command and everything afterwards is the output of the command.

Is there something similar in `powershell` that would print out the executed command?

```
=== script 

$myVar = C:\
ls $myVar

=== output

+ ls C:\
....
02/14/2023  09:19 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               1 File(s)            681 bytes
              18 Dir(s)  514,576,928,768 bytes free
```